# String to DATETIME in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, datetime

I would like to convert strings to datetime objects to be used in the insert statement for **MySQL**. The strings are received in the following format :

```
2010-12-21T22:57:04.000Z
```

The data type of the **MySQL** column is *DATETIME*.

Comment: As far as I know, DATETIME column type does not support milliseconds, so you would lose that bit of information. Is this ok?

Comment: Hexa, YES. I wouldn't mind losing the milli seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function.

For instance, that would give:

```
myDatetime = datetime.strptime(myString.split(".")[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

**[EDIT]** Well, I've seen this has been treated in another thread with a better answer than mine: [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, The dateutil.parser function looks good. I get the following : 2010-12-21 22:57:04+00:00 
Would this do for the datetime column?

Comment: @Denzil: i can't see why it wouldn't but i am often using DAL when Python programming so i am not an expert in this part. Btw, as hexa pointed out, you'll probably loose your miliseconds. You should try and see if it behaves as you wish